# understanding and using hasOwnProperty

Tags: actionscript-3

Can someone explain to me how to assign and use hasOwnProperty. I did search the web for a decent example but somehow didnt find any even at adobe( or maybe Im to "smart" to understand what it is saying )

so what Im trying to do is to set a propertie onto a MovieClip and after that to see if it exists.

```
    var myMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
myMC.hasOwnProperty( "someRandomText" );

this.addChild( myMC );
if( myMC.hasOwnProperty( "someRandomText" ) ) trace(" yes it has it ")
else trace( "nothing here" )
```

output: `nothing here`

what am I doing wrong ?

and also :) how do I null/remove it after I add it to the MC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty()` checks whether an object has a property of that name. Basically, it'll return true if a property has an instance name matching the string.

The reason `hasOwnProperty("someRandomText")` returns false in your code is simply because `myMC.someRandomText` does not exist. Your second line seems to try making it but that's not what the function does.

A better test would be:

```
if( myMC.hasOwnProperty( "width" ) ) trace(" yes it has it ");
else trace( "nothing here" );
```

All `MovieClip`s have a `width` property so this should return true. I haven't tested it but it should work.

[The definition on the AS3 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29) is pretty much the best explanation you can get.

Comment: so there is no way I can create assign  `("someRandomText")` to the myMC except if I dont go in the MovieClip Class and there create such a property

Comment: To add a custom property, you'll have to make your own custom class that extends `MovieClip` and either 1) define the property in there, or 2) declare the class with the `dynamic` keyword. The `dynamic` keyword allows you to create new properties at runtime (e.g. `myMC.someRandomText = "foo"`).